# How to convert list of lists into groups in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to solve an exercise which i have a list of list like this:

```
outerlist = [[344,0,"str1"],[233,0,"str2"],[213,0,"str3"],[344,2,"str4"],
             [213,1,"str5"],[344,3,"str6"],[344,1,"str7"],[213,2,"str8"]]
```

second elements in inner lists are always increase consecutively.

And want an output like this:

```
Group 1
213 0 str3
213 1 str5
213 2 str8
Group 2
233 0 str2
Group 3
344 0 str1
344 1 str7
344 2 str4
344 3 str6
```

At first I tought about grouping by first element of list and write this code

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []
for i in range(len(outerlist)):
    if outerlist[i][0] == 213:
        list1.append(outerlist[i])
    elif outerlist[i][0] == 233:
        list2.append(outerlist[i])
    elif outerlist[i][0] == 344:
        list3.append(outerlist[i])
```

But outerlist can have more inner lists as elements, and these inner list can have different elements in first element (instead of only 213, 233 ,344 it could be 579 or 1000 thus in output there must be a group 4 and group 5 section)
If I could solve this first problem I can use these functions, and groups can be ordered consecutively
and I could print them

```
def sortinlist(y):
    y.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
    return y
def listtostr(y):
    return ' '.join(map(str, y)
```

But i don't know how many inner lists will be in the outerlist and want to find a code that can detect ids with looking first element of the innerlist, create a new list for this id, then looks for first element in the second inner list, if its id is same as first innerlist's id append to group 1 list if it isnt then creating a new list, and so on. Basically I want to find a way to give output with example structure.

Comment: Are you allowed to use python dictionaries to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, at first outer list i wrote was a .txt file like
344 0 str1\n
233 0 str2\n
but i convert it to list thinking it could be easier to manipulate

Answer (score 1):

A solution using sets and lists :

```
labels = list({l[0] for l in outerlist})
sortedlist = sorted(outerlist) 
groups = [[l for l in sortedlist if l[0]==x] for x in sorted(labels)]

for  i,values in enumerate(groups):
    print("Group",i+1)
    for v in values:
        print(*v)
```

produces

```
Group 1
213 0 str3
213 1 str5
213 2 str8
Group 2
233 0 str2
Group 3
344 0 str1
344 1 str7
344 2 str4
344 3 str6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dictionary of the group keys to the elements that appear to them. [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is used to ensure values are always lists.

```
 from collections import defaultdict 

 outer_list = sorted(outerlist, key=lambda seg: seg[0])
 d = defaultdict(list)
 for seg in outer_list:
     d[seg[0]].append(d)

 for group_idx, group in enumerate(d.values()):
     print(f'Group {group_idx + 1}')
     print('\n'.join(map(' '.join, group))))
```

If you don't want to import `defaultdict` (or can't), you can do something like this

```
 d = {}
 for seg in outer_list:
     d[seg[0]].setdefault([])
     d[seg[0]].append(d)
```

Comment: It was not sorted from the beginning :D that's the trouble) check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here we are

```
outerlist = [[344, 0, "str1"], [233, 0, "str2"], [213, 0, "str3"], [344, 2, "str4"],
             [213, 1, "str5"], [344, 3, "str6"], [344, 1, "str7"], [213, 2, "str8"]]
outerlist = sorted(outerlist, key=lambda x: x[1])

last_id, group_id = None, 0
for item in sorted(outerlist, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    if not last_id or item[0] != last_id:
        group_id += 1
        last_id = item[0]

        print('Group {}'.format(group_id))

    print(' '.join([str(x) for x in item]))
```

Outputs

```
python test.py
Group 1
213 0 str3
213 1 str5
213 2 str8
Group 2
233 0 str2
Group 3
344 0 str1
344 1 str7
344 2 str4
344 3 str6
```

> For the case we don't have to build any extra lists or complex structures for printing.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bit like a homework problem so I'm not going to do all of it for you but I do think that by using a dictionary you'll be able to get most of the way there

This addresses the primary concern of

> But outerlist can have more inner lists as elements, and these inner list can have different elements in first element (instead of only 213, 233 ,344 it could be 579 or 1000 thus in output there must be a group 4 and group 5 section) If I could solve this first problem I can use these functions, and groups can be ordered consecutively and I could print them

```
outerlist = [[344,0,"str1"],[233,0,"str2"],[213,0,"str3"],[344,2,"str4"],
             [213,1,"str5"],[344,3,"str6"],[344,1,"str7"],[213,2,"str8"]]

container = {}
for inner_list in outerlist:
    key_, ind_, string_ = inner_list

    if key_ in container:
        container[key_].append([ind_, string_])
    else:
        container[key_] = [[ind_, string_]]
```

At this point, container contains

```
{344: [[0, 'str1'], [2, 'str4'], [3, 'str6'], [1, 'str7']],
 233: [[0, 'str2']],
 213: [[0, 'str3'], [1, 'str5'], [2, 'str8']]}
```

which you can then sort

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in a `dict` like this:

```
def group_by_id(data):
    grouped_data = {}

    for element in data:
        id = element[0]
        elements_same_id = grouped_data.get(id, [])
        elements_same_id.append(' '.join(element))
        grouped_data[id] = elements_same_id

    return grouped_data

for group_number, group in enumerate(group_by_id(outerlist), 1):
    print(f'Group {group_number}')
    for element in group:
        print(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it the following way:

```
outerlist = [[344,0,"str1"],[233,0,"str2"],[213,0,"str3"],[344,2,"str4"],
             [213,1,"str5"],[344,3,"str6"],[344,1,"str7"],[213,2,"str8"]]


def sortinlist(y):
    y.sort(key = lambda x: x[0])
    return y

groups = {}

for group in outerlist:
    groups[group[0]] = groups.get(group[0], []) + [(group[1], group[2])]


for group in groups:
    group = sortinlist(groups[group])

group_id = 1
for group in sorted(groups.keys()):
    print("Group %d" % (group_id))
    for member in groups[group]:
        print("%d %d %s" % (group,member[0],member[1]))
```

1. Put every element of the list into a dict with the key the group (344, 213, 233, ...) and the value a list of the data as a tupel of two: [(0, "str1"),(2, "str4")...]
2. Order it by the first value of the tuple so that the string in the group are in the right order
3. print it out ordered by keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to convert your list to a dictionary and you can output the sequence.

It sorts the lists based on 1st, 2nd, 3rd elements in the list and converts to a dictionary and prints it.

```
dt={}
count = 1

for i in sorted(outerlist,key=lambda x:(x[:])):
    dt[i[0]]=dt.get(i[0],[])
    dt[i[0]].append(i)

for i in dt.values():
    print('Group ', count)
    count += 1
    for j in i:
        print(' '.join(map(str,j)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bad option, but I wanted to make it a way to create a new variable for each item, I recommend the use of dictionary for such purposes, but already contains good answers above and in this case I will only post this way I thought, but remembering that the use of dictionary must be the best

```
outerlist = [[344,0,"str1"],[233,0,"str2"],[213,0,"str3"],[344,2,"str4"],
             [213,1,"str5"],[344,3,"str6"],[344,1,"str7"],[213,2,"str8"]]

count = 0
for l in outerlist:
    try:
        assert count != 0
        for c in range(count):
            if l[0] == locals()[f'new_list_{c}'][0][0]:
                locals()[f'new_list_{c}'].append(l)
                break
            if count == c + 1:
                raise UnboundLocalError
    except:
        locals()[f'new_list_{count}'] = [l]
        count += 1

for c in range(count):
    print(f'Group {c+1}')
    for n in locals()[f'new_list_{c}']:
        print(*n)
```

### Output

```
Group 1
344 0 str1
344 2 str4
344 3 str6
344 1 str7
Group 2
233 0 str2
Group 3
213 0 str3
213 1 str5
213 2 str8
```

and you can have the variable printed

```
print(new_list_0)
print(new_list_1)
print(new_list_2)
```